# excel 'IF' 'OR' formula working but need blank option

Tags: excel

I have successfully set up an 'IF' 'OR' formula that reviews the data of three cells and selects G unless one of the 3 cells contains an R in which case it displays R

```
=IF((OR('Jan 16'!B33="G",'Jan 16'!B34="G",'Jan 16'!B35="G")),"G","R")
```

The problem that I have is if there is no data populated into the logical test cells ('Jan 16'!B33, 'Jan 16'!B34 or 'Jan 16'!B35) the result is R. When the logical test cells contain no data I need the result to be blank.

Any help provided would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Like: `=IF((OR('Jan 16'!B33="G",'Jan 16'!B34="G",'Jan 16'!B35="G")),"G",IF((OR('Jan 16'!B33="",'Jan 16'!B34="",'Jan 16'!B35="")),"","R"))`?

Comment: ugly, but `if(..., 'G', if(b33='' and b34='' and b35='', '', 'r')`?

Comment: @ScottCraner You need to do the blank test first as he says any blanks require the result to be blank.

Comment: If @Chrismas007 is correct, I had a different understanding which upon a reread I think he is, use this: `IF((OR('Jan 16'!B33="",'Jan 16'!B34="",'Jan 16'!B35="")),"",IF((OR('Jan 16'!B33="G",'Jan 16'!B34="G","R"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'IF' 'OR' formula that reviews the data of three cells and selects G
>   unless one of the 3 cells contains an R in which case it displays R

```
=IF((OR('Jan 16'!B33="G",'Jan 16'!B34="G",'Jan 16'!B35="G")),"G","R")
```

Alright, I'm not sure if that's what you meant to say or not, because right now, it is backwards.  If any of the three cells contains a G, the formula will return G.  All three cells would have to NOT contain G in order for it to return R.  For example, even if you had data that was `R|R|G`, the formula would return a G (not R).

To get a formula as you've originally described, yet have it return blank if any of the three cells are blank, you could use this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK('Jan 16'!B33:B35)>0,"",IF(COUNTIF('Jan 16'!B33:B35,"R")>0,"R","G"))
```

To adjust your existing formula as you posted in your original question, you would use this:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK('Jan 16'!B33:B35)>0,"",IF(COUNTIF('Jan 16'!B33:B35,"G")>0,"G","R"))
```

**EDIT**: Per additional requirement provided in comment:

> Is there any way that I could add a third letter "Y"... so if in the
>   combination of three cells it is blank then return a blank, if in the
>   three cells there is an R return R, if in the three cells there is a Y
>   but no R then return Y and finally, if there are three G's return G

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK('Jan 16'!B33:B35)>0,"",IF(COUNTIF('Jan 16'!B33:B35,"R")>0,"R",IF(COUNTIF('Jan 16'!B33:B35,"Y")>0,"Y","G")))
```

Or if it specifically needs to look for 3x G:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK('Jan 16'!B33:B35)>0,"",IF(COUNTIF('Jan 16'!B33:B35,"R")>0,"R",IF(COUNTIF('Jan 16'!B33:B35,"Y")>0,"Y",IF(COUNTIF('Jan 16'!B33:B35,"G")=3,"G","Invalid Data"))))
```

Comment: The first formula worked well; thank you. Is there any way that I could add  a third letter "Y"... so  if in the combination of three cells it is blank then return a blank, if in the three cells there is an R return R, if in the three cells there is a Y but no R then return Y and finally, if there are three G's return G